# Sniffing packets of specific binaries / apps / process id?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffer, dtrace

Is there a way to associate packets with executing binaries?  I would be open to traditional sniffing methods or even `dtrace` for that matter.

I have a specific issue on a system with very high traffic.  Sniffing "all" packets and filtering them is becoming a very burdensome problem and eliminating packet emission from all but the offending app is not possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I ran into a really nice solution for this problem and wanted to share.  It is found in the DTrace Book: http://www.dtracebook.com

You'll want to pull down the examples from here: http://www.dtracebook.com/images/dtbook_scripts.tar.gz

I'm running no OS X.  I extracted the scripts to `dtbook` under my `~/bin` and executed the appropriate script as follows:

```
sudo ~/bin/dtbook/Chap6/soconnect_mac.d
```

Which will then give you all processes with their connections.  I usually pipe that into `grep` and search for apps specifically now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention what OS you're running on said system, but if it's running Windows you can use Microsoft Network Monitor, which shows the process ID for each "conversation" so it should allow you to focus your analysis. "Filtering" traffic per process ID is as simple as selecting the process in the left pane and viewing it's traffic in the right pane.

Comment: Right, thanks.  I thought that with mentioning `dtrace` it would be a little more evident.  This is an OS X server, however I likewise would similarly want to be able to apply this to Linux based servers and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is what you require, but netstat can help you associate process id with network port. In wireshark you can then filter on that port number, to only sniff a specific process id's packets.

Comment: Yes, this had crossed my mind, however I had hoped to find a more simplistic way to cross reference the pids with packets.

Answer (score 1):

On windows there is an experimental build that does this, as described on the mailing list: http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/201212/msg00069.html